# How to perform a multi label classification with tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I'm new to tensorflow and would like to know if there is any tutorial or example of a multilabel classification with multiple network outputs.

I'm asking this because I have a collection of images, in which, each image can belong to several classes and my output needs to have a score of each class.

I also do not know if the tensorflow follows some file pattern of the images and the classes, so if someone has some example it would facilitate a lot.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try transforming your problem from a multi-label to multi-class classification using a Label Powerset approach. Label Powerset  transformation treats every label combination attested in the training set as a different class and constructs one instance of a multi-class clasifier - and after prediction converts the assigned classes back to multi-label case. It is provided in [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml) and scikit-compatibility wrapper over the tensorflow Estimator or via an [input_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/input_fn/) or use [skflow](http://terrytangyuan.github.io/2016/03/14/scikit-flow-intro/). Then just plug it into an instance of [LabelPowerset](http://scikit.ml/api/api/skmultilearn.problem_transform.html#skmultilearn.problem_transform.lp.LabelPowerset).

The code could go as follows:

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import LabelPowerset
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow

# assume data is loaded using
# and is available in X_train/X_test, y_train/y_test

# initialize LabelPowerset multi-label classifier
# with tensor flow DNN base classifier
classifier = LabelPowerset(skflow.TensorFlowDNNClassifier(OPTIONS))

# train
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What I'm kind of lost is how I relate my images to classes. In the documentation of the tensorflow I found no example type. Would you know how to relate my images to classes? In my case I would think it would be something like:

Image1 class1
Image1 class2
Image2 class5
Image 2 class1
Image3 class 4

And so on..

Answer (score 2):

The most naive (and reasonable) approach would be to train a classification network, and remove the softmax layer and replace it with a vector of sigmoids. This way you can have multiple units with an activation of 1.

You can see [on TF-slim](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/slim#Training) examples for classification networks. Under the path `datasets` you will find examples on how to prepare the `TFExample` "file pattern" for images and classes

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions refer to sigmoid loss, and sigmoid do solve multi-label classification well in my case by `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels,logits)` in tensorflow.

However, when I handled class unbalance problem, where negative cases is much more than positive cases, I found my edited softsign loss worked much better than sigmoid. The adjust coefficient `gamma` is added to label to lower negative class's gradient by 3/4.

```
def unbalance_softsign_loss(labels, logits):
    gamma = 1.25 *labels - 0.25 
    res = 1 - tf.log1p( gamma*logits/(1+ tf.abs(logits)) )

    return res
```

where labels is multi-hot encoding vectors like [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], logits ~ (-inf, inf)

Comment: How many unique label set do you had? for my case 35 [0,1,0,0,0,...35th col index] and above "unbalance soft sign loss" worked well? Could you give the base reference paper?